# Is there an implementation of the Penn Treebank Tokenizer in Perl?

Tags: perl, nlp

I'm looking for a Perl module that is a port of [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed) where I can basically create an object, call a tokenize() subroutine, pass in a pile of text and get back a list of tokens.  Something to that effect.  If it doesn't exist I'll do it, but no sense in reinventing the wheel, right? :)  TIA.

Comment: Broken link: https://web.archive.org/web/20151201051654/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed

Comment: porting `sed` to `perl` should be easy ;P

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an exact match, but could one of [Lingua::EN::Tagger](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aTagger), [Lingua::Treebank](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3a%3aTreebank), [Text::StemTagPOS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text-StemTagPOS), [Lingua::Stem::Snowball](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3a%3aStem%3a%3aSnowball) or [Treex::EN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Treex%3a%3aEN) handle the problem?

Comment: Thanks.  I've found several Perl modules that perform tokenizing, but they don't specifically say they're ports of the Treebank one, so I can't quite tell if they're following it.  The modules you suggested are actually for either working with data in the Treebank format or for stemming words (ex: taking a word "skiing" and reducing it to "ski"), as opposed to taking a sentence and dividing it up into tokens like: "as", "opposed", "to", "taking" "a" "sentence", "and", "dividing", "it", "up", "into", "tokens", "like", ":".  Sorry for not being too clear before.

Comment: You might read the "Higher Order Perl" section on tokenizing, it might be very easy to write this. The book is free online.

Comment: Cool, I'll check that out!  Yeah, I have a feeling I'll be writing this.  Not a big deal since it's a pretty short sed script that already practically looks like Perl, but still. :)

Comment: One caveat. The standard sed script (from http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenization.html) is a pretty good starting point, but isn't advertised as exactly matching the Penn Treebank standards (see the note at the bottom of that page). For example, the treebank splits 'Ph.D.' into 'Ph. D.' and labels both parts as NNP (appropriate since it's an abbreviation for Doctor of Philosophy). The sed version doesn't handle that case. I suspect there might be a few other edge cases as well.